# Change RasterBrick dimensions from TXY to XYT

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I am trying to import a `netCDF` file into a `RasterBrick` in `R`. The `netCDF` file has 3 dimensions.

```
library(ncdf)
nc <- open.ncdf("fm100_2003.nc");
print(nc)
[1] "file fm100_2003.nc has 3 dimensions:"
[1] "lon   Size: 1386"
[1] "lat   Size: 585"
[1] "day   Size: 365"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file fm100_2003.nc has 1 variables:"
[1] "short dead_fuel_moisture_100hr[day,lon,lat]  Longname:dead_fuel_moisture_100hr Missval:-9999"
```

The size of the day dimension correspond to daily fuel moisture for one year (365 days). I'd like to import these into a `RasterBrick` for additional analysis which is pretty straightforward with,

```
r <- "fm100_2003.nc"
b <- brick(r,varname="dead_fuel_moisture_100hr")
```

However, the issue is that the `ncol` and `nlayers` in the `RasterBrick` are switched, which results in an incorrect `rasterLayer` for each layer in the brick. The dimensions of the `RasterBrick` should read 1386, 585, 505890, 365 instead of the dimensions below:

```
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 1386, 365, 505890, 585  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent      : 37619.5, 37984.5, -124.793, -67.043  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : fm100_2003.nc 
names       : X49.3960227966309, X49.3543561299642, X49.3126894632975, X49.2710227966309, X49.2293561299642, X49.1876894632975, X49.1460227966309, X49.1043561299642, X49.0626894632975, X49.0210227966309, X48.9793561299642, X48.9376894632975, X48.8960227966309, X48.8543561299642, X48.8126894632975, ... 
degrees_north: 25.0626894632975, 49.3960227966309 (min, max)
varname     : dead_fuel_moisture_100hr
```

I am wondering if there is any way to specify the dimensions when creating the `RasterBrick` to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution (or perhaps work around) to the above problem.

I first import the `netCDF` file into an array in `R`.

```
dname <- "dead_fuel_moisture_100hr"
array1 <- get.var.ncdf(nc, dname) 
dim(array1)
[1]  365 1386  585
```

The dimensions of array1 are: days, columns, rows. However, I can change the dimensions of the array:

```
array2<-aperm(array1, c(3, 2, 1))
dim(array2)
[1]  585 1386  365
```

Now the array is organized properly: rows, columns, days. At this point I can access the depth range I need (days 1 through 365) as a matrix:

```
fm.day.001<-array2[,,1]
...
fm.day.365<-array2[,,365]
```

The matrix can be converted to a raster too:

```
r2<-raster(nrow=585,ncol=1386,vals=fm.day.001, xmn=-124.7722, xmx=-67.06383,  ymn=25.06269, ymx=49.39602)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rather strange, why the dimension is not correct. You could explore your ncdf file by using some command below:

```
# Open your dimension
# following by '$' you can use tab to see the next available command (R Studio)
r$dim

# REad value for each dimension
lon = get.var.ncdf(r, varid='lon')
lat = get.var.ncdf(r, varid='lat')
time = get.var.ncdf(r, varid='day')
```

Comment: Thanks @Eko. I am able to explore the ncdf file and the dimensions look right. Although, I think in your example the code would be: lon = get.var.ncdf(nc, varid='lon')

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `dims` argument. Something like:

```
b <- brick("fm100_2003.nc", varname="dead_fuel_moisture_100hr", dims=3:1)
```

This is experimental. Even if it creates the correct object, the object may not work for subsequent operations.

Comment: Thanks for the input @RobertH. Your code appears to create the correct object, a rasterbrick, but the rows and columns are still switched 1386 rows, 585 columns. Perhaps this is related to the format of this particualar netCDF data? That is what set me down this path from the start.